# I am new to data structures and was trying,but whenever i am using my index function to find the index of the number its returning -1 as value

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;

    Node(int Data)
    {
        data = Data;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

//This FUNCTION is used to return the index value of the integer we trying to find
int index(Node *head, int find)
{
    Node *temp = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        count++;
        if (temp->data == find)
        {
            return count;
        }
        else
        {

             // It should return -1 only when it doesn't find the particular variable

             return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Idk why but it is always return -1 as value and I am not able to understand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help [ask]

Comment: Wouldn't you want to go through _all_ the nodes before returning `-1`?

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. A debugger comes with every development worth using on desktop hardware. With a debugger you can control the execution of the program and monitor the changes in state. Typically you will use breakpoints to get to regions of interest in the program and then step through the code line-by-line while keeping an eye out for the program doing something unexpected like taking the wrong path or storing the wrong value.

Comment: You check the **first** value, if it's not what you seek you immediately return from the function (with -1)

Comment: You put `return -1;` in the wrong place. It should be after the while loop not inside it.

Comment: C++ now comes with many data structures built in and it will save yourself a lot of time if you get familiar with the data structures in the Standard Library. e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Answer (score 0):

What happens if the first node does contain the value that you want? Does it return 0?

Your conditional statement always results in a return statement, so it will return 0 if the first Node contains the value that you want, -1 if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You put your `return -1` as the `else` condition when the current node you're inspecting doesn't match what you're looking for. What you really want to do is `return -1` after you've exhausted all the nodes (i.e. after your `while` loop)

It also makes the function more correct as it would return a value in all circumstances. At the moment if you pass NULL for `head` you haven't defined what should happen.